# How to solve problem "4967 - Tri graphs" ICPC Live Archive

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

Firstly, I'm so sorry for my English is not very well!!!
This is the link to go to that problem: https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=2968

**Brief description:** Find the minimum cost from middle node on top of the graph to the middle node at the bottom of the graph.

The cost of a path will be the sum of all nodes that it traverses through.
[image]

So, I think I should use LCBFS algorithm to solve this problem, but my algorithm is not good enough so my code was be time limit exceeded. This is my code: http://codepad.org/lJIYOPon. Anyone can help me to optimize my code, thank you so much.

Comment: What is LCBFS meaning? For working code, you may reach out to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) for help.

Comment: It helps to solve weighted graphs with BFS

Comment: I think this problem can solve layer by layer, row by row. You don't need to use a full scale Dikjstra/LCBFS for this problem. Let me know if you are not able to figure it out, I will add a proper answer.

Comment: http://codepad.org/ZLcoTKUB this is my code using Dijkstra to solve this problem, but it still time limit exceeded

Comment: OK, I understood your idea, thanks you so much, this problem can be solved in O(n)

Comment: Do share your final solution as answer for this question, then mark it as accepted so that we could close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I solved it (and got `Accepted`):

I used bottom-up dynamic programming approach, which allowed me to come up with a `O(n)` time solution with `O(1)` for memory.

Let's use a dynamic programming table and calculate what is the minimum cost for the node on each `row` and `col` (i.e. `dp[row][col]`). We will start from the last row and will proceed to the first one (bottom-up).

Lets store the "graph" in a 2D array, called `graph`, with size `[n][3]`.

First, it's easy to see what's the cost if we were dealing with one row (the last one).

1. `dp[0] = graph[n - 1][0] + graph[n - 1][1]`, because if we are at column `0` and then jump to the neighbouring column (reaching the target), the answer will be the sum of the nodes in the first and second column.
2. `dp[1] = graph[n - 1][1]`, for the same reason.
3. `dp[2] = infinity`, because if we are at the last column on the last row, we will not be able to reach the target.

Knowing this, let's now assume we have two rows in our graph, the we'd like to calculate the asnwer for the first row. Note that the answer is for the second row is already known.

If we are on the first row (with index 0), then we can calculate another `dp`, lets call it `next`. In order to calculate `next[1]`, we should first calculate `next[2]`, because from the first column we can reach the second and we have to know the answer for `next[2]`.

1. `next[2] = graph[0][2] + min(dp[1], dp[2])`, because from the first row, standing at column `2`, we can go down to the next row to column `1` and `2`. We already know the minimum for the next row, stored in the prevously calculated `dp` array.
2. `next[1] = graph[0][1] + min(next[2], min(dp[0], dp[1], dp[2]))`. Think about why this is calculated like that.
3. `next[0] = graph[0][0] + min(next[1], min(dp[0], dp[1])`

We can proceed in the same manner and calculate the minimum in the general case for `N >= 2`.

Note that we only can store the last three calculated values, because from the `i`-th row  we can go the `i + 1`-th, and thus we don't have to store the whole `[n][3]` table, but only the last row. This observation boosts down the memory complexity to `O(1)`!

Here's my code in Java (I have omitted the part with reading the input):

```
private long dp(int[][] graph) {
  int n = graph.length;
  long[] dp = new long[3];
  dp[0] = graph[n - 1][0] + graph[n - 1][1];
  dp[1] = graph[n - 1][1];
  dp[2] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

  for (int row = n - 2; row >= 0; row--) {
    long[] next = new long[3];

    next[2] = graph[row][2] + min(dp[1], dp[2]);
    next[1] = graph[row][1] + min(next[2], min(min(dp[0], dp[1]), dp[2]));
    next[0] = graph[row][0] + min(next[1], min(dp[0], dp[1]));
    dp = next;
  }
  return dp[1];
}
```